# Add next visible object's id to link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What i'm trying to do here is get the id of the next fieldset of the current visible one, so that when I press next it loads it with the id of the next fieldset.

The best it seems to achieve is getting one of the next id's but stops.

```js
$(".next").on("click", function() {

  $('this').attr("href", function() {
    return "#" + $('fieldset:visible"').next("fieldset").attr("id");
  });
});
```

```css
a{position:fixed;left:0;bottom:0;z-index:999;background:black;color:#fff;padding:50px;}
html,body,fieldset{width:100%;height:100%;}
fieldset{position:relative;}
#one{background-color:red}
#two{background-color:green}
#three{background-color:blue}
#four{background-color:red}
#five{background-color:green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="next" href="#two">NEXT</a>
  <fieldset id="one"></fieldset>
  <fieldset id="two"></fieldset>
  <fieldset id="three"></fieldset>
  <fieldset id="four"></fieldset>
  <fieldset id="five"></fieldset>
```

Comment: They are all visible.

Comment: You have to make one hidden.

Comment: Each time you click, it always starts with first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `location.hash` with helper class `active` as shown the snippet below.

Hope this helps.

```js
$(".next").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('fieldset.active').removeClass('active').next("fieldset").addClass("active");

  location.hash = "#" + $('fieldset.active').attr('id');
});
```

```css
a{position:fixed;left:0;bottom:0;z-index:999;background:black;color:#fff;padding:50px;}
html,body,fieldset{width:100%;height:100%;}
fieldset{position:relative;}
#one{background-color:red}
#two{background-color:green}
#three{background-color:blue}
#four{background-color:red}
#five{background-color:green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="next" href="#">NEXT</a>
<fieldset id="one" class='active'></fieldset>
<fieldset id="two"></fieldset>
<fieldset id="three"></fieldset>
<fieldset id="four"></fieldset>
<fieldset id="five"></fieldset>
```

Comment: DUH. Thanks mate. Will take this once able to in a few mins

Answer (score 0):

You can first hide the clicked one and then get ahead with visible ones

```js
$(".next").on("click", function() {

  $(this).attr("href", function() {
    var f= $('fieldset:visible:first');
    f.hide();
    return "#" + f.next("fieldset").attr("id");
  });
});
```

```css
a{position:fixed;left:0;bottom:0;z-index:999;background:black;color:#fff;padding:50px;}
html,body,fieldset{width:100%;height:100%;}
fieldset{position:relative;}
#one{background-color:red}
#two{background-color:green}
#three{background-color:blue}
#four{background-color:red}
#five{background-color:green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="next" href="#two">NEXT</a>
  <fieldset id="one"></fieldset>
  <fieldset id="two"></fieldset>
  <fieldset id="three"></fieldset>
  <fieldset id="four"></fieldset>
  <fieldset id="five"></fieldset>
```

Comment: Sorry not suitable for what im doing though technically does it so will give a plus 1 for it thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
$(this)...
```

You do not need quotes.